# Triggering a checkbox set based on multiple values in mulitple fields FM Pro 15 Adv

Tags: function, if-statement, filemaker

We have a situation whereby we need to establish a clausal function querying data from two fields.

We have an 'Item Purchased' field, and five second hand item fields (SH Item 1, SH Item 2, etc). If either (or both) of these fields contain one of a list of specific products by name, a checkbox is enabled (ticked) which in turn triggers conditional formatting.

We have the checkbox and the formatting in place, but I can't find an eloquent means to make an IF query using Case or PatternCount etc to trigger the checkbox - I'm a little out of my depth!

I've attempted (successfully) to use a simple nest of IF statements to trigger the checkbox

- but there must be a better way to trigger a 'true' result over a list of values, rather than copying repeating it i.e (Item Bought="Roland"; "Yes"; (sh item 3="Roland"; "Yes"; etc:

If(Item Bought="Orla"; "Yes"; If(sh item 1="Orla"; "Yes"; If(sh item 2="Orla"; "Yes"; If(sh item 3="Orla"; "Yes"; "No")))

I was hoping to learn of a better way to query the presence of a dozen or so discrete values over several discrete fields.

Comment: This is kind of difficult to follow. The one thing that stands out is that you have 5 numbered fields. That is a symptom of poor data structure, and it will cause you endless problems down the road - even if you find a workaround for your current issue. Instead of multiple fields, you should be using multiple records in a related table.

Comment: Hi Michael - I completely agree! It is a mish-mash and pretty well most of my coding on the database is a band-aid. I'm inheriting the database second hand and our needs have evolved a lot since it's early days, to the extent that I might consider rewriting the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick fix for your issue could be:

```
Let ( 
values = List ( Item Bought ; SH Item 1 ; SH Item 2 ; SH Item 3 ; SH Item 4 ; SH Item 5 )
;
not IsEmpty ( FilterValues ( "Orla" ; values ) )
)
```

---

This will return a result of 1 (True) if any of the listed fields contains the value "Orla", 0 (False) otherwise - so you can use it directly as the formula for conditional formatting.

However, as I stated in a comment above, this is not a good solution overall.

Comment: Thanks for this Michael

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you can easiest use an OR operator between the criteria in your IF or CASE statement to get what you want. Also, check out the Filtervalues function as it looks to be relevant to your need.

Comment: Thanks Andreas - I had considered this but wasn't certain of the best way forward.